# Gradle build scripts found - what does this dialog really do?

Tags: android, android-studio

I was doing a simple project in Android Studio. I thought it best to use git, so I exited Android Studio and then did a local `git init` followed by `git add .` and `git commit -m "first commit"`.  Routine thing to do to preserve progress.

When I restarted the IDE, I was greeted with the dialog below asking if I want to "Load Gradle Project" or "Skip".  I tried it both ways.  Clicked "Load Gradle Project" the first time. Then rolled back the current git changes (various .idea directory files) and clicked "Skip". In both cases, the project still works and builds fine.

What does Load button do and why does it not seem to matter if I click it or not?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **Load Gradle Project** dialog in Android Studio triggers a sync with the Gradle build scripts to ensure the IDE's configuration matches the project's build settings.

Clicking **Load** imports and applies these settings(which includes downloading dependencies, setting up the project structure, and preparing the project for execution).

While **Skip** bypasses the sync. It might be useful if you know there have been no changes to your Gradle configuration and you want to quickly get to work without waiting for the sync process to complete.

Your project works either way because Android Studio might be using a previously synced state. It's usually best to **Load** to keep everything up-to-date.

Comment: Thanks. If "skip" is clicked, but it really shouldn't have, does the sync eventually happen on the next build?

Comment: Yes, the Android Studio will eventually perform a gradle sync the next time a build is triggered.